# Need to call function written inside a shell script from node js

Tags: node.js, shell

I need to call a function written inside a shell script from node js. I have tried the command "source test.sh a" , where 'a' is the method inside test.sh in shell command. It works but from nodejs how to call it using execFile/spawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With child_process *spawn*, you could do it with the `{ shell: true }` option (to spawn a shell), but it seems that the *exec* method is more appropriate in this case:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('source ./test.sh && a');
```

Comment: It throws me an error saying 'source' command not foud. 
Were you able to run the above snippet?

Comment: You may not have that command on your system, see https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do

Comment: I have source command on my system but NodeJs child_process runs in shell and that may not have source command supported. 
Were able to run exec with source?

Comment: Won't work if function has dots in them. Not relevant. Just saying. Valid in bash, not in nodejs.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the comment. Do you have an alternative?